# jQuery Validation for min and max date for particular age

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having need to enter DOB, but user's minimum age should be 18 years and maximum age should be 60 years

For that jQuery method is added, but not responding well, on any DOB it shows Maximum age is 60 years allowed

**code of jQuery method**

```
 $.validator.addMethod("minDate", function (value, element) {
    var min = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-60 year"));?>);
    var inputDate = new Date(value);
    if (inputDate < min)
        return true;
    return false;
}, "Maximum Age 60 Years");

$.validator.addMethod("maxDate", function (value, element) {
    var max = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-18 year"));?>);
    var inputDate = new Date(value);
    if (inputDate > max)
        return true;
    return false;
}, "Minimum Age 18 Years");
```

**rules of form validation**

```
"user[DOB]": {
                required: true,
                minDate:true,
                maxDate:true
            },
```

Comment: *"not responding well"* does not help us.  You need to troubleshoot this a bit and then explain to us what you've tried.  Have you inspected the DOM?  Does your PHP render within the JavaScript as expected?  Are  you seeing any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: I think you need to switch around your `return true;` and `return false;` for both. As it stands,The first statement will return true (valid) for a date less than `Date 1969-12-27T20:53:39.834Z`

Comment: I'd suggest changing your `curDate` variable names as It's confusing. Try `minDate` and `maxDate` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you have your validation backwards. You're returning true if invalid, false otherwise.

Try:

```
$.validator.addMethod("minDate", function (value, element) {
    // new Date(-356780166)..
    var min = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-60 year"));?>);
    var inputDate = new Date(value);
    if (inputDate < min)
        return false;
    return true;
}, "Maximum Age 60 Years");

$.validator.addMethod("maxDate", function (value, element) {
    var max = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-18 year"));?>);
    var inputDate = new Date(value);
    if (inputDate > max)
        return false;
    return true;
}, "Minimum Age 18 Years");
```

If that doesn't work, see what your inputDate is returning e.g `console.log(inputDate);`

Comment: What's not showing any error? When the input is valid?

Comment: in any case, whether input is valid or not

Comment: What does your `var input` look like? Or the `value` paramater?

Answer (score 0):

```
        mindob= new Date(2021 - 12, 12 - 1, 30)
        // Wed Dec 30 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        maxdob= new Date(2021 - 18, 12 - 1, 30)
        // Tue Dec 30 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)



        current = new Date(2000,12,30)
        // Tue Jan 30 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        current>=maxdob
        // false
        current<=mindob
        // true
        (current<=mindob && current>=maxdob)
        // false
        current = new Date(2004,12,30)
        // Sun Jan 30 2005 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        (current<=mindob && current>=maxdob)
        // true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

sorry for troubling you all, thanks for all support - below code solved my error

```
$.validator.addMethod("dobRange", function (value, element) {
        var min = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-60 year"));?>);
        var max = new Date(<?php echo date("U",strtotime("-18 year"));?>);
        var inputDate = new Date(value);
        if (inputDate < min || inputDate > max)
            return false;
        return true;
    }, "Age Limit 18 to 60 Years");
```

Comment: Or just replace the last three lines with one:  `return (inputDate < min || inputDate > max);